# What does Tatooine's farside look like?

Tags: star-wars, star-wars-legends, tatooine

In the *Star Wars* Prequel trilogy, we are shown only one side of Tatooine, while the other is on the far side:

[image: Tatooine]

What does the other side (hemisphere) look like? Is there a map of the area?

Comment: What does the other side look like? Sandy. What kind of weird crazy planet *doesn’t* have the same type of environment over its entire surface???

Comment: Oh, yes, of course, but I meant areas of hills and canyons, such as the Jundland wastes in New Hope, they must be on the back side, and the Dune Seas.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

We see a ship approaching Tatooine from a different angle in [Star Wars: The Clone Wars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_Wars:_The_Clone_Wars_(2008_TV_series)). As you can see, the topography is very similar to that of the other side.

[image]

---

This image below comes courtesy of [Star Wars: The Old Republic](http://www.swtor.com/info/holonet) (and as such is non-canon) but again, we can see the general character is that of a featureless desert-world.

[image]